# Is it possible to embed java program (or applet) in a pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, applet, embed

I was wondering if it is possible to embed a java program or an applet into a pdf file. Any way of achieving this is okay for me (latex, adobe acrobat pro, etc).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adobe has support for Javascript.  I do not believe they support the ability to embed a Java applet ( thank god ).

Comment: Do you want to include the Java source code or the actual executable?

Comment: @Rob: Of course actual executable!

Comment: You do realize that it would be a horrible idea if you could embed executables in a PDF?

Comment: @cularis: Problem is: Not "it would be", but rather "is". I don't get the rationale behind that, though. See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html .

Comment: *"I was wondering if it is possible to embed a java program or an applet into a pdf file. "*  Sure.  You can dump any old set of bytes into a PDF.  No reader will run it though.

Comment: Guys, I just asked a question! Lot's of negative feedback! I understand the risk of security but you may also consider that you are running applets in your browsers without vulnerability. Anyway, thanks for replys.

Answer (score 4):

No. Not if you are not talking about security holes, anyway.

[Escape From PDF](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2010/03/29/escape-from-pdf/), great blog about security. For educational use only.

Comment: He he, it was my first idea to do it like maleware in PDFs do.

Answer (score 4):

You can embed just about anything in a PDF as an attachment.

And clicking on an "attachment annotation" gives the user the option to either view/launch or save it locally.

You can create such annotations programmatically in a number of different libraries (such as iText/iTextSharp), or use the Acrobat Pro UI to do it By Hand.

You can also embed Flash into a PDF, and control its execution to some extent via script in the PDF.  If you can figure out how to wrap a .jar or convert it to SWF, you're there.